# IOS Document Provider Extension: Identify host application

Tags: ios, document-provider

I am working on an application that has a secure container for files. From the security needs we have to prohibit document extension for host applications that are in a black list. Are there any opportunities to identify bundle/name of the host app.

I have tried to get access for NSXPCConnection * _auxiliaryConnection; in NSExtensionContext but it is nil. (https://github.com/CPDigitalDarkroom/iOS9-SpringBoard-Headers/blob/master/usr/lib/libextension.dylib/NSExtensionContext.h)

Talking about document extension provider I mean (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html)

Thanks!